# How do i get qt/c++ to work with mysql on a mac?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am somewhat new to qt/c++ (coming from a php/sql world) and I am trying to get my qt c++ app to connect to my mysql database on my localhost.

I understand that I need to create a plugin to connect to the mysql driver? Do I need to recompile qt? qt creator? Apologies if the question is a bit confusing, but I am a bit lost.

Thanks in advance.

I am using MAMP for the mysql. Mac is 10.6 (64 bit).

Comment: Couldn't you just use the standalone mysql connector library?

Comment: Not sure. Can you give me a link?

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-unix-and-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following step-by-step instruction: http://zamslivenet.fatcow.com/zamswiki/index.php?title=TechBase:MacOSX:Qt

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why that was so hard for me to find.